# Google Analytics for multilanguage site with same root domain

Tags: google-analytics

i've developped a multilanguage site and now i'm wondering how i can best track them using Google Analytics. I want to track both languages separatly but i also want to get a general overview. The url's of my site are:

rootdomain.com/ --> which has a splash page
rootdomain.com/nl --> which is the dutch site
rootdomain.com/en --> which is the english site

the rootdomain is the same in every language.

Can someone help me?

kind regards,

Daan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create a filter for every language (subdirectory)

http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55530

Comment: That link no longer work, which is precisely why it's frowned upon to not put some actionable information in your answer. *sigh*